# Device descriptor in lufa... What kind of structure is this (inside)? I think it is nothing specific, and only a question to C/C++ programmers

Tags: c99, avr

I am using [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) for a project and after reading some of the examples I saw some of these constructs. Are these macros? I know AVR devices and know that PROGMEM is one? But what is .Header and why is it starting with a ".".

Can someone explain to me how to create contructs like these or show me where I will find them in the LUFA documentation?

```
USB_Descriptor_Device_t PROGMEM DeviceDescriptor =

{
    .Header                 = {.Size = sizeof(USB_Descriptor_Device_t), .Type = DTYPE_Device},

    .USBSpecification       = VERSION_BCD(01.10),
    .Class                  = USB_CSCP_NoDeviceClass,
    .SubClass               = USB_CSCP_NoDeviceSubclass,
    .Protocol               = USB_CSCP_NoDeviceProtocol,

    .Endpoint0Size          = FIXED_CONTROL_ENDPOINT_SIZE,

    .VendorID               = 0x03EB,
    .ProductID              = 0x2045,
    .ReleaseNumber          = VERSION_BCD(00.01),

    .ManufacturerStrIndex   = 0x01,
    .ProductStrIndex        = 0x02,
    .SerialNumStrIndex      = USE_INTERNAL_SERIAL,

    .NumberOfConfigurations = FIXED_NUM_CONFIGURATIONS

};
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a C99 way of naming members of a struct, so you can give the values in an arbitrary order. I believe the term is "designated initializers". Not part of C++.

Comment: Thank you! The buzzword "designated initializers" was a good hint. The rest I found here: http://axelio.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/designated-initializers/

Answer (score 0):

As [Bo Persson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052206/device-descriptor-in-lufa-what-kind-of-structure-is-this-inside-i-think-it/5052517#5052517) said, *this is the C99 way of initializing a struct*.  The LUFA documentation for [`USB_Descriptor_Device_t`](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/101122/html/struct_u_s_b___descriptor___device__t.html) says that the `Header` field is a [`USB_Descriptor_Header_t`](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/101122/html/struct_u_s_b___descriptor___header__t.html).

You should probably [read up on designated initializers](http://www.dmk.com/c/init.html) a little if you are going to be dealing with C99 code.  You can translate your snippet into:

```
USB_Descriptor_Device_t PROGMEM DeviceDescriptor;
memset(&DeviceDescriptor, 0, sizeof(DeviceDescriptor));
DeviceDescriptor.Header.Size = sizeof(USB_Descriptor_Device_t);
DeviceDescriptor.Header.Type = DTYPE_Device;
DeviceDescriptor.USBSpecification = VERSION_BCD(01.10); /* beware of leading zeros! */
DeviceDescriptor.Class = USB_CSCP_NoDeviceClass;
DeviceDescriptor.SubClass = USB_CSCP_NoDeviceSubClass;
DeviceDescriptor.Protocol = USB_CSCP_NoDeviceProtocol;
/* etc etc etc */
```

I think that explicit initialization is easier to read in this case, but designated initializers do have their uses.